Photons are massless then how do they exist?
If something exists, then it surely has some mass. If photons are massless then they simply should not exist. But they not only exist but have momentum(p) also despite the fact that p=mv and if m=0 then p also equals zero.

Why can't something massless exist? Say, for example, your memories of your childhood - does that have mass, or does it not exist?

Also, $p=mv$ is a Newtonian equation, it's only approximately correct in relativity, but it's an excellent approximation when $v\ll c$

Maybe mass is just a form of energy

Maybe it would be worth to define what means "to exist" in a scientific and non-opinion based way.

This question is similar to: If photons have no mass, how can they have momentum?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi Gourav and welcome to the Physics SE :-) It seems strange that things without mass can exist, but in physics mass is a stranger thing than you think. If we go to a high enough energy all fundamental particles become massless. It's just one of those things that you need to get used to when you learn physics. It's a good question though :-)

@Allure information might have mass, though...
